# Is there any way of getting the virtual key code from char in C++?

Tags: c++, keycode

Is there any way of getting this? I'm using the `INPUT` class to to simulate key presses, and when wanting to press the key in a variable of type `char`, I need to use the following method:

```
INPUT ip;
ip.type = INPUT_KEYBOARD;

//a bunch of code, and flags...

ip.ki.wVk = toupper(foo);
```

...where foo is of type `char`, and user-defined.

This works fine, until the user inputs a character that's not a regular letter, which results in a completely different key being registered (which is understandable). That's why I'm asking if there's possibly a method that makes me able to get the hexadecimal key code from the variable's value?

I know that I can make a big `switch(foo) case '1': //and so on...` to replace the unsupported characters with their corresponding key code, but really, that would mean a lot of unnecessary code.

So, is there any way? Answer is highly appreciated, and if there aren't any, I'll go a head and solve it in a more complicated way. However, since this issue has occured for me several times by now, I figured that it might be good to know for reference.

Comment: I think you want `VkKeyScanEx(...)` http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms646332(v=vs.85).aspx

Comment: This is not standard C++, so what environment are you using? (It resembles SDL, but I'm not sure)

Comment: @msandiford Thanks a lot! However, do you perhaps know how to get that function working? Honestly, I'm kind of new to programming in general, and this didn't work: `cout << VkKeyScanEx('c', (LoadKeyboardLayout(0x1053)))`. Apparently, the function can't get overloaded, which means that I need some sort of locale identifier as the second argument... I wasn't expecting that to work, but in case you need to know, it was intended for a Swedish keyboard.

Comment: Nevermind, I solved it using GetKeyboardLayout(0) instead. Thanks again!

Comment: `GetKeyboardLayout(0) ` seems to load current system keyboard layout of the program's window :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To turn my comment into an answer...

I think you want [`VkKeyScanEx(...)`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms646332%28v=vs.85%29.aspx).  This will turn a `TCHAR` into a virtual keycode and a set of keyboard modifiers that you should be able to use with [`SendInput(...)`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms646310%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)

Comment: First, you need to have some keyboard layout: `HKL currentKBL = GetKeyboardLayout(0);` then you can call something like `VkKeyScanEx( YOUR_CHAR, currentKBL );`